# Single session enforcement using signalR/Long polling

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I want to implement single session enforcement in my application. Meaning if another login activity found for the same user in different browser/different machine then then first session should get auto logoff. If I use the Ajax polling then unnecessary network traffic will happen. So am planning to use signalR.
For that i tried simple click event. Its working without refreshing the page from browser 1 to browser 2.

I created hubclass and my cshtml as follows

```
var myHub = $.connection.myHub;

$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.start(); 

myHub.client.Postmessage = function (message) {
$('#message1').append('<li><strong>'+ htmlEncode(messaage) + '</li>')
$("btnClick").click(function () (
 
var message = $('message').val();
myHub.server.helloServer(message);
$('#message1').val('').focus();
```

External service class to find the session details

```
 private static ISSEnforcementSvc ssEnforcement; 
 public static SSEnforcementSVC GetSSEnforcementService()
 {
   if (ssEnforcement == null)
   {
    var localService GetLocalizationsvc;
    var configurationSvc = GetConfigurationSvc();
    var cacheSvc = GetCacheSvc(); 
    ssessionEnforcement Service = new 
    SinglesessionEnforcementService(localService, 
                            configurationSvc,cacheSvc)
    }
   return ssEnforcement;
 }
```

Please suggest how to implement same way to push the 1st browser to logoff.

Comment: You are approaching this the wrong way. And it is really not enough information to go on. Server should be the one disconnecting the clients. You can not have logic on frontend. I have big experience with singalR and to handle anything regarding connection on ui is wrong.

Comment: got your point, How can I approach it from server side. Pleas suggest

Comment: It all depends on how your hub(s) work. Do you have service to manage users (like on connected add to db or to memory and so on). Do you have c# code?

Comment: Yes I have external service call to find the user session details. But how can i use this attributes inside my hubclass  . Question updated.

Comment: 1. when clients conects check iif it in users (dict with email and connection id and then, in your cases where ever use store connected users) GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<ITransportHeartbeat>().GetConnections().First(c => c.ConnectionId == "YourId").Disconnect(); or something like 
2. or same as one just do Context.Abort();